# Change location of RSS Dynamic Desktops

Tags: windows-7, desktop, rss, ccleaner

I'm currently using CCleaner to take care of my computer, but I also have a dynamic desktop background provided by Bing (I'm running Windows 7 HP) - and unfortunately the two conflict. Whenever I 'clean' my computer using CCleaner it messes up my destop backgrounds as they are stored  in the temporary internet files directory, and for some reason I don't appear to be able to get as far as the 'Enclosures' sub directory in order to tell CCleaner to exclude the directory (I can see it in Windows Explorer but not in CCleaner's directory browser).

Therefore, I am looking for an alternative solution to this problem and wondered if I could change the directory to which the images were  downloaded on the RSS feed. If anybody knows how to do this, I would be grateful if you could share or indeed, I would be equally as greatful if anyone knows any other ways of getting around CCleaner. Please note that I don't want to stop cleaning the whole of my temporary internet files though - I just don't want the wallpapers that have been downloaded to be deleted...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of things then it doesn't seem like there is an answer to this question, without getting your hands dirty anyway. Search engines, nor this website has yield any answers unfortunately; therefore I took it upon myself to make a solution.

Using my knowledge of Java I have created an application that sits in the background and periodically checks a specified RSS feed. If there are any new entries, the application will process the tag containing the image URL and download it to a user defined directory. I can now tell Windows to use all the images in the directory that the program downloads to as a Desktop Slideshow. The application is only very simple but if anybody would like a copy please ask and I will happily upload it.